# Can tags or synonyms be blocked from being used or blacklisted?

Tags: support, tags, blocked-tags

Are there any blacklisted tags on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)?  In addition, is there a way with moderator access that you can blacklist a tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there are blacklisted tags.

The full list can be read by the diamond moderators.

Only the development team have the ability to edit the list.