# Supplement the tag blacklisting feature with a warning when trying to use any tag that has previously been removed

Tags: feature-request, tags, warning

Sometimes we decide a tag that is in use is not a very good idea and we remove it, perhaps by editing every question that has it.

But a new user comes along who doesn't know the history and naively uses the useless tag.

Wouldn't it be handy if the system put up some kind of barrier to make this a bit harder.

Perhaps just a warning in red when you try to submit like we already have for questions with the word "best"... perhaps a warning in the place where tag wiki excerpts are displayed while typing in the tags section... perhaps some other way.

Of course sometimes a tag becomes unused for some other reason and recreating it later does make sense after all. So it probably shouldn't be completely blocked... at least not as the default - maybe for real problem tags.

The system could keep track of all the tags which were invented but later went out of use. For instance in the db there might be a "number of uses" field for each tag, which for these tags would be `0`. When somebody tries to tag a question with one of these "`0` use tags" it shows the warning, or whatever action is deemed appropriate.

If the db doesn't currently remember which tags have gone out of use, one of the SE devs could write some script that finds them from dumps, backups, etc, and puts them in the db as "`0` use tags".

---

This is not asking about the difficult manual process of [blacklisting tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122545/can-tags-or-synonyms-be-blocked-from-being-used-or-blacklisted) (permanently **blocking** them, requiring an SE dev. This is about the system **warning** an editor that a tag might not be acceptable.

Both features can coexist but are not at all the same thing.

Comment: Already done, see the linked post.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: I wasn't asking about blacklisting. I should've mentioned the contrast perhaps. Blacklisting requires the mods of a site manually getting the attention of a SE dev and convincing them to **block a tag permanently**. I'm asking for the system to automatically to **warn the user the tag might not be a good idea.**

Comment: OK, sorry for that. Problem is that I don't think the system "remembers" removed tags; The data is there somewhere, but I don't think there is a record of "past tags".

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: No worries. I even suggested a way to dig up the old tags to implement the future. But even if we had to start with a blank slate it would still be useful.

Comment: Related: [If a tag existed, and then is removed, raise reputation needed to add tag again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131585)

Comment: Well it seems Jim, Gamecat is Toon Krijthe, Martijn Pieters, ChrisF all clicked on close too fast to read the difference to my proposal and blacklisting. At least none of them left any comments. I'm voting to reopen. Help me out if you think this is different enough from blacklisting.

Comment: Agreed. @Jim can you cast the final reopen vote?